# so i want to use ffmpeg with heroku but i keep getting the error that i dont have ffmpeg installed

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

so i made a bot for fun on and its okay when i run it like on replit or my local pc but on heroku it wont work . i did add the heroku's ffmpeg to buildpacks but it still give me the same error also the codes are available at github
https://github.com/amirdadfar9192/Goorbe_bot

```
2021-12-10T13:13:54.043169+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043248+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043249+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043264+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/bot.py", line 125, in p

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043264+00:00 app[worker.1]:     song = await player.play()

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043287+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/DiscordUtilsMod/Music.py", line 196, in play

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043287+00:00 app[worker.1]:     source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(self.music.queue[self.ctx.guild.id][0].source, **self.ffmpeg_opts))

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043302+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 225, in __init__

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043302+00:00 app[worker.1]:     super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043316+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 138, in __init__

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043317+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self._process = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043330+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 147, in _spawn_process

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043331+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise ClientException(executable + ' was not found.') from None

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043357+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.errors.ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043372+00:00 app[worker.1]: 

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043373+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043373+00:00 app[worker.1]: 

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043388+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043416+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043416+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043432+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043432+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043447+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped

2021-12-10T13:13:54.043447+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc

2021-12-10T13:13:54.045338+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.
```

Comment: "i did add the heroku's ffmpeg to buildpacks"—how did you do this? What is the output of [`heroku buildipacks`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-buildpacks)?

Comment: @Chris i did it through the gui in website not CLI . i just went to heroku app and then settings then scrolled down to buildpacks and added this link there https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git

Comment: And what is the output of `heroku buildpacks`?

Comment: @Chris sorry im new.how can i see the output you mean in logs?

Comment: if you mean on the logs there is nothing there it just saying that your dyno is now up and then there will be my print function that i said print bot is online

Comment: I mean if you run `heroku buildpacks` on the command-line, what does it show you? I'm trying to see your exact buildpack configuration.

Comment: @Chris ```=== gorbe Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
2. heroku/python```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i just needed to update my github code for heroku to create a new build and install ffmpeg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).